# Move objects with jquery depending on resize and/or load

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a navigation bar placed just after the header on a website.

I'd like to move this object right after the opening body tag if the user resizes the window to less than 768px, but return it to it's original position if they make the browser wider than this amount.

The navigation bar is loading in the correct place if the page loads depending on browser width, but I really want to get this working with on resize as well.

Any suggestions?

The code I have is very basic so far…

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    if (width < 768) {
        $('#customMenu').prependTo('body');
    }
}); // END:jQuery(document).ready(function(){
```

Comment: I'm not sure of your browser requirements, but have you considered using `@media` queries in CSS? http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Hi Richard, I've already tried @media queries but the trouble is we have some elements at the top of the page that are causing a problem. If I set the position to fixed the drop menu's do not scroll properly and relative, causes a problem with an ad spot. It's all a bit of a pain really ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand but if you want to trigger function on resize event you can use:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    var winWidth = $(window).width();
    if (winWidth < 768) {
        $('#customMenu').prependTo('body');
    } else {
        $('#customMenu').prependTo('#somewhereElse');
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this need to go inside the .ready function? I've tried it and it's working great, but when i load the window larger than 768, resize it (it goes to the correct place) and then scroll, the nav moves back to its default position and won't stay at the top of the page

Comment: Isn't there a problem with CSS ? Because I have no idea why it should move back to its defaut position on scroll. Can you post a jsfiddle ? Or your code ?